# exit_form(no_validate) in oracle forms

Tags: validation, oracle10g, exit, oracleforms

I have a doubt.
why we have to specify **exit_form(no_validate)** twice on the trigger "when_button_pressed",to exit from the form without validating.
why is it validating even if I give no_validate in exit_form.

P.S: my form status is "changed"

Please help me in understanding the underlying concept as I am new to oracle forms

Answer (score 3):

The reason why you'll have 2 x `EXIT_FORM` is due to the way that Forms handles query modes.

- If the form is in data entry mode, only 1 `EXIT_FORM` is needed to exit the form.
- If the form is in query mode, the first `EXIT_FORM` will cancel the query mode but the form will remain open. A second `EXIT_FORM` will then exit the form.

Therefore, 2 x `EXIT_FORM` calls are guaranteed to always close the form.

If your form is still validating, I suspect the validation is happening *before* your `when-button-pressed` trigger is firing - i.e. when the user clicks on the button, which probably has **Mouse Navigate** set to **Yes**, Forms must first navigate the cursor to the button; this probably causes item-level validations (and possible record-level as well) to fire.

If you want the button to exit the form and cancel any validation etc., I believe you need to set **Mouse Navigate** to **No**.

Comment: Your option 1 in enter query mode should not be the case because he is mentioning that the status is changed and that won't be right if you are in enter query mode. But for the rest you are correct.

Comment: @nightfox79, yes, as I said, only one 1 exit_form is required when not in query mode. The whole point is that the extra exit_form IS required for when the form is in query mode - the OP asked why there were two.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have the property navigable and or mouse navigate on the button on and at the moment you press it the validate from the item you are standing on fires.
You should put navigable and mouse navigate property off.